# In Angular, Communicating a matching $index between two different directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I have two directive:

```
<wa-svg ng-repeat="page in Pages" ng-mouseover="showTooltip($index)>

<wa-tooltip ng-repeat="page in Pages" ng-class="{on: matchedIndex}">
```

**Question:**

On mouseover of a specific `wa-svg`  how do I match the `$index` of `wa-svg` to make the `matchedIndex` of `wa-tooltip` return true.  Thus, the class of `on`gets appended to `wa-tooltip`

I believe it will take an isolate scope or maybe possible through `ng-model` but it's confusing.

Note: *I cannot nest these elements because wa-svg is a svg object and you cant nest very well unless using foreignObject and blah blah blah.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm how about a shared controller then?

A wrapper controller which has this function:

```
  $scope.showTooltip= function($index) {
       $scope.hoveredIndex = $index;
  }
```

And in your tooltip directive do:

```
  <wa-tooltip ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{on: $index === hoveredIndex}">
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: I think so... testing.

Comment: +1 This approach is similar to, but better than, mine.

Comment: is it? i thought it's better to create a dot notation?  because of that members issue?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<div ng-init="hovered = {}">
  <wa-svg ng-repeat="page in Pages" ng-mouseover="hovered.index = $index" />
  <wa-tooltip ng-repeat="page in Pages" ng-class="{on: hovered.index == $index}" />
</div>
```

To sum up:
Hovering over the `wa-svg` sets the `hovered.index`, which you can access in `wa-tooltip`.

The only reason for the `hovered = {}` part is because the repeaters create new scopes, so I've created an object outside of the new scope, so that the index is accessible from both repeaters.  You could / should put that statement into a controller.

Comment: ahh this is prettier; esp if the hovered is in the parent ctrl.

Comment: Thanks this was easier than I thought ... long day!

Comment: I actually like @Pinhas' answer better ... that avoids the new scope issue, so it's less fragile than my answer.

Comment: And here I was liking your answer better :)

Comment: So, the "dot notation" thing is confusing.  It's needed if you're **setting** a value in your **template** (in the `ng-mouseover` directive), because the value gets put on the current nested scope, which can't be seen outside that scope.  But if you set the value in the controller (in the `showTooltip` method), then you avoid the workarounds.